# How to write Typescript Conditional type structure for Array items to depend each other?

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors, typescript-typings

I'm created a function by give the Array of the Objects that contain icon key.
for `icon` key if one of the index on array filled by value, another index should filled, and if not one fill `icon` key and pass `undefined` to it, another index should be undefined.

For Example :

```js
type Item = {
    title: string;
    icon?: string | undefined;
};

function Func(items: Array<Item>) {
    return items.map((item) => item);
}

Func([
    { icon: 'home', title: 'Home' },
    { icon: 'phone', title: 'Phone' },
    { icon: 'user', title: 'User' },
]); //=> no error

Func([
    { title: 'Home' },
    { title: 'Phone' },
    { title: 'User' }
]); //=> no error


Func([
    { icon: 'home', title: 'Home' },
    { icon: 'phone', title: 'Phone' },
    { title: 'User' },
]); //=> should be error, cause icon not set for `user` but set for another

Func([
    { icon: 'home', title: 'Home' },
    { title: 'Phone' },
    { title: 'User' }
]); //=> should be error, cause icon set for `home` but not set for another
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Update the Types to :

```js
type ItemsWithoutIcon = Array<{ title: string }>;
type ItemsWithIcon = Array<{ title: string; icon: string }>;
type Items = ItemsWithIcon | ItemsWithoutIcon;
```

and use in `Func` by :

```js
function Func(items: Items) {
    return items.map((item) => item);
}
```

Or

```js
type ItemsWithoutIcon = { title: string };
type ItemsWithIcon = { icon: string } & ItemsWithoutIcon;
type Items = Array<ItemsWithIcon> | Array<ItemsWithoutIcon>;
```

That mean, the `items` arg should be array of object without contain `icon` property, all other item should be same, and if contain `icon` property, all should be contain `icon` property.